# Adding pivoting functionality to a Doolittle algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, linear-programming, factorization

So far I have this code for an LU decomposition. It takes in an input array and it returns the lower and upper triangular matrix.

```
void LUFactorization ( int d, const double*S, double*L, double*U )
{
   for(int k = 0; k < d; ++k){
       if (
      for(int j = k; j < d; ++j){
         double sum = 0.;
         for(int p = 0; p < k; ++p) {
             sum+=L[k*d+p]*L[p*d+j];
             cout << L[k*d+p] << endl;
         }
         sum = S[k*d+j] - sum;
         L[k*d+j]=sum;           
        U[k*d+j]=sum;
      }
      for(int i = k + 1; i < d; ++i){
         double sum=0.;
         for(int p = 0; p < k; ++p) sum+=L[i*d+p]*L[p*d+k];
         L[i*d+k]=(S[i*d+k]-sum)/L[k*d+k];
      }
   }

   for(int k = 0; k < d; ++k){
      for(int j = k; j < d; ++j){
         if (k < j) L[k*d+j]=0;
         else if (k == j) L[k*d+j]=1;
      }
   }
}
```

Is there some way I can adapt this to perform row exchanges? If not, is there some other algorithm I could be directed towards?

Thanks

Comment: Before I can provide a full answer, are you aware that, since you iterate from `j=k` to `d`, the condition `k <= j` is always true? Thus you store the same information about the upper diagonal matrix in L and U, only zeroing it later in `L`.

Comment: yes, I realized this and I have edited it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual approach for LU decompositions with pivoting is to store a permutation array `P` which is initialized as the identity permutation (`P={0,1,2,...,d - 1}`) and then swapping entries in `P` instead of swapping rows in `S`

If you have this permutation array, every access to `S` must use `P[i]` instead of `i` for the row number.

Note that `P` itself is part of the output, since it represents the permutation matrix such that
`P*A = L*U`, so if you want to use it to solve systems of linear equations, you'll have to apply `P` on the right-hand side before applying backward and forward substitution